# How do I work-around Java's block on static method extension?

Tags: java, methods, static, extend

I'm building a parser for a compiler, and what I would like to have a class (`static`) method for each term the parser finds. This method should return a regular expression which can be used to determine whether the token that the Scanner provided is that term and express it as a `boolean` value. It should be a `static` method that all derivative classes are guaranteed to have.

Unfortunately, the Java language does not take kindly to this kind of method extension. The code would either not compile, or reference the wrong edition of the method. I'm sure I'll come up with a few workarounds myself, probably involving reflection or a careful `HashMap`; but this isn't the first time I've run into a problem like this one, and I'm curious. Has anyone else here come up with a solution that provides passable extensibility of `static` methods?

---

Okay, let met clarify. I am not looking for a why-doesn't-this-compile, nor am I looking for a how-do-I-make-this-work. I am looking for a method by which I can check a method, which does not require the class to yet be instantiated, which can be relied upon to exist for any extending class. And, it needs to work in my weapon of choice for this project, that is, Java.

As we all know that what I am discussing is in fact not a static method (pardon me, I thought I was clear about that), there is no code to show you; and what I do have is largely tangential. What I have come up with is this, in an abstract constructor:

```
public Item(String token) {
    if(!check(token)) {
        throw new MismatchException(this.getClass() + " cannot be instantiated for \"" + token + "\"");
    }
    this.setData(derive(token));
}

public abstract boolean check(String token);
```

Meanwhile, creation of each token (and in this instance, addition to the abstract parse tree) goes like this (though I believe that it's still in need of a little polishing):

```
for(Sting token : tokenList) {
        for(Class<?> cls : buildables) {
            try {
                Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(String.class);
                result.add((Buildable)constructor.newInstance(c.toString()));
            } catch(InvocationTargetException ex) {
                //"MismatchException" is my own creation, for this exact purpose
                if(ex.getTargetException() instanceof MismatchException)
                    continue;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //Again, a point for polishing:
                ex.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

### So, the problem is solved, as long as all extensions fit those parameters. If you have another suggestion on how this can be done, I'm game for it.

As an addendum, for those who really want to see the code of my current project, you can grab everything completed (and pushed) from github at https://github.com/MichaelEricOberlin/Builder-Tutorial . It's of course meant to be public anyway.

**Edit (David Wallace):**

So we have a class `Foo` with a method `public static void bar()` - or possibly a different signature.  Then we have subclasses `RedFoo`, `GreenFoo` and `BlueFoo` each with its own version of `public static void bar()`.  Obviously, this is illegal in Java.  The question is how to work around this.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example? I can't understand what you want, and what the problem is.

Comment: When asking about a compilation problem, wouldn't it be wise to post the code that causes the problem? That and the actual error message?

Comment: Your idea seems obscure! `have a class (static) method for each term the parser finds`--- ???

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels-This is a suggestion question,not the compilation error problem. Please go through it once again SIR...

Comment: @Bohemian How is this unclear?  This seems perfectly clear to me.  It's unclear why you closed this.

Comment: @DavidWallace I might be jaded, but much of the text is irrelevant, there's no code (even if not compiling), JB and HCFOE didn't understand it (and they are smart) and asked for clarification. If you understand it perhaps you can edit it for clarity - reopened.

Comment: This smells very much like an XY problem. A static method is useless unless you already know about the exact implementing class at compile-time. The sort of thing you're saying you want to do is **exactly** when you should have that method on an interface (and possibly `abstract` on a base class) and just use a collection of instances.

Comment: @Bohemian OK I've tried to clarify the question.  Of course, I think that wanting to do this is a sign of either poor design, or poor understanding of what static methods are for.  But at least now, we might get some answers here.  There's no code, because this is a "how do I do this" question, not a "this doesn't work" question.

Comment: This is simply not in any way how you write a compiler or even a lexical analyser. You write, or preferably generate, a single lexical analyser that tells *you* what the token was. Have a look at JavaCC, ANTLR, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it more or less as follows:

A class `Symbol` for terminal symbols (one RegexSymbol suffices) and nonterminal symbols (NonTerminalSymbol, SequenceSymbol, AlternativesSymbol, ...).  The child classes may be package local.

A class `Token` with a field Symbol, and a start and end position: a symbol *occurrence*.

A class `Grammar` which has factory methods for symbols.

```
Grammar myGrammar = new Grammar() {
    Symbol op = regex("\\+|-|\\*|/");
    Symbol number = regex("\\d+");
    Symbol expr = nonterminal();

    {
        define(expr,
            alternatives(seq(number, op, expr),
                         number));
    }
};
```

Not sure, how this maps on your case. But I separate grammar (Symbol) from the AST abstract syntax trees or parsed token occurrences.

Comment: I actually came up with something similar. Symbols are already passed in as tokens, as pulling them out of the raw code string is part of the scanner's task; this is related to the job of the parser. Provided a list of symbols, it checks against each symbol (in the proper order of operations) in the constructor of the Term. It creates the term if it finds a match, and throws a specific exception if it doesn't, thus continuing the loop to the next most significant Term.

This may be a better notion than my original design anyway; but I think you see the benefit of a flexible class-level regex.

Comment: In some respects a protected `method` is similar to what you are searching (inheritance of static), namely it can return something static final. Good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you here, Mr. Eggen. Can't public, private, and package methods do the same?